# Closing laptop lid doesn't suspend however it's enabled in gnome-tweaks

Tags: power-management, laptop, asus

Ubuntu 22.04 on Asus laptop with Intel 11th gen.
I can see lid (close/open) actions in dmesg only without suspending the laptop.

Comment: What's the output of `gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power | grep lid`? Is it connected to power and do you have any external monitors connected when closing the lid?

Comment: You must have as much swap space as you have RAM in order to hibernate. Do you? Look at `free;sudo lshw --class memory`.

Comment: @waltinator, that's for hibernating, not suspending